# Save foreach() output into array (Smarty)

Tags: php, content-management-system, smarty

How to save foreach output to another array in Smarty and use new array outside of {foreach}?

Example:

```
{foreach name=cats from=$category->subcategories item=n}

/*here would be something like $newArr = ($n->name,$n->url)*/
{/foreach}

<a href="$newarr->name">hi</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about smarty but easy way to do this in PHP is using the [array_push](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function. Or do it with the []  (same thing really) :

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($oldArr as $oldArr) {
   $newArr[] = $n->name,$n->url;
   // EQUIVALENT TO
   array_push($oldArr, $n->name,$n->url);
}
```

Comment: The question was about Smarty, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it from code behind. Smarty is for **View** layer and such layer shouldn't have possiblity to do something on variables other than showing it. You can save output to array in php code and then assign it to your view. But if you really want to do it in smarty you can use **php tag** http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl but I don't recommend it.

There is also one interesting tag

**{append}**

{append} is used for creating or appending template variable arrays during the execution of a template.

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.append.tpl

Comment: thanks for info, but when i try to use {php} tags it doesn't show output of array
{php}
   

foreach $category->subcategories as $n{
echo $n;}

{/php}
but {php} $n = 1; echo $n{/php} works excellent. So can you tell me how i can save output to array in php code? Thanks.